# How to unmute audio using Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have added mute function to my game, I know I can simply mute all audio on webpage by calling function mutePage(), but I was wondering how Can I make it unmuted back again without reloading a page.

```
function sound(src) {
    this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
    this.sound.src = src;
    this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
    this.sound.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    this.play = function(){
        this.sound.play();
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        this.sound.pause();
    }    
}

function muteMe(elem) {
    elem.muted = true;
    elem.pause();
}

function mutePage() {

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll("audio");

    document.getElementById("snd").style.textDecoration = "line-through";

    [].forEach.call(elems, function(elem) { muteMe(elem); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a button that your player clicks. Add an event listener to the button and inside of it mute your Audio Object.

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.sound.muted = false;
});
```

be sure to use an arrow function otherwise "this" will be scoped to the event handler context